# Python regex - Ungreedy quantifier question

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I messed up an earlier question and deleted it (provided a poor example that led to incorrect solutions). *Mea Culpa*

Here it is again, stated more correctly. *I also need to cover cases where the 2 is not the first char of the string.*

I have this string:

```
bobsmith2kgminus10meshcompt3kgfredrogers
```

I wish to only return the `2`.

Here is my regex:

```
.*(\d+?)kg.*
```

It is returning `3` and I don't see what I've missed.

[RegEx101.com Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugPdJF/1)

My python code:

```
import re
val = 'bobsmith2kgminus10meshcompt3kgfredrogers'
out = re.sub(r'.*(\d+?)kg.*', r'\1', val)
print(out) #prints: 3
```

I've also tried:

```
(.*)(\d+?)kg.*
(\d+?)kg.*
```

Comment: You just want to match first quantity in kg right ?

Comment: ? makes the preceding quantifier lazy thus causing the regex to match as few numbers as possible. This does not mean that it will be fewer matches but the match will be the smallest possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `re.sub` then use:

```
.*?(\d+)kg.*
```

This will 0 or more characters *as few times as possible, expanding as needed* before matching and grouping `\d+`.

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> val = 'bobsmith2kgminus10meshcompt3kgfredrogers'
>>> print ( re.sub(r'.*?(\d+)kg.*', r'\1', val) )
2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugPdJF/3)

---

Otherwise, you can use this simpler regex in `re.search`:

```
(\d+)kg
```

**Code:**

```
>>> print ( re.search(r'(\d+)kg', val).group(1) )
2
```

Comment: You got it - that works. But can you please explain to me why the `?` after the capture group did not work? From my less-advanced understanding of the ungreedy quantifier, it is the capture group that should be ungreedy... (that is, stop after the first one)?

Comment: I have added an explanation. Having lazy quantifier after `\d+` won't really make any difference since regex has already consumed longest match using `.*` before that.

Comment: As I explained in the main question : ? makes the preceding quantifier lazy thus causing the regex to match as few numbers as possible. This does not mean that it will be fewer matches but the match will be the smallest possible.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this expression might simply work:

```
(\d+)kg.*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NxSaqp/1)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(\d+)kg.*"

test_str = """
2kgminus10meshcomp3kg
some_content_before200kgminus10meshcomp3kg
"""
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['2', '200']
```

Or with `re.sub`:

```
import re

regex = r".*?(\d+)kg.*"

test_str = """
2kgminus10meshcomp3kg
some_content_before200kgminus10meshcomp3kg
"""
subst = "\\1"
print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

Comment: I appreciate the extra info about `findall` - many thanks. +2